# python . making matrix with list

Tags: python, matrix

I want to make matrix with list

What I want to make is this following .

```
coll = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]
```

What I want to make is this following .

```
matrix = [
    ["AA:AA","AA:BB","AA:CC","AA:DD"],
    ["BB:AA","BB:BB","BB:CC","BB:DD"],
    ["CC:AA","CC:BB","CC:CC","CC:DD"],
    ["DD:AA","DD:BB","DD:CC","DD:DD"],

]
```

I am newbie in Python ... Could someone give me how to do and with some references or explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way to implement this is a two-tier list comprehension.

```
coll = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]
matrix = [
  ['%s:%s' % (a, b) for b in coll]
  for a in coll
]
```

Another way to put it that might be easier to understand is

```
matrix = []
for a in coll:
  row = []
  for b in coll:
    row.append('%s:%s' % (a, b))
  matrix.append(row)
```

but the result will be the same:

```
print(matrix)
[['AA:AA', 'AA:BB', 'AA:CC', 'AA:DD'],
 ['BB:AA', 'BB:BB', 'BB:CC', 'BB:DD'],
 ['CC:AA', 'CC:BB', 'CC:CC', 'CC:DD'],
 ['DD:AA', 'DD:BB', 'DD:CC', 'DD:DD']]
```

Comment: So great .. Thanks. Even though for beginners it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved by my *easy and  *shy way

```
coll = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"]

mat = [[0]*4 for i in range(4)]

i = j =0


for xx in coll :
    for yy in coll :
        mat[i][j] = xx + ':' + yy 
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0

print(mat)
```

I appreciated with all guys.